# Top Navigation Bar Drop Down Arrow

Tags: 2010, navigation, top-link-bar

Some of my top nav bar items have multiple levels.  The arrow to the right of the item which denotes multiple levels is currently black.  What is the class or id that is used so I can change the color to white?  Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 1):

If you study the html rendered of the menu, its noticed that menu is rendered in `ul li` structure. And the black arrow is nothing but the background image given to a span.

Screen shot of the rendered html

[image]

Below class is used (*rare chances but may vary based on which updates are applied or different versions like standard, enterprise extra.*)

```
.menu-horizontal A.dynamic-children SPAN.additional-background {
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-image: url(/_layouts/images/menu-down.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

So in order to change it, you need another image which can replace it or override css and use tricks to design a triangle/arrow.

If you decide to use another image then,

```
.menu-horizontal A.dynamic-children SPAN.additional-background {
    background-image: url('your image url')!important;
}
```